# oracle 10g merge multiple records for a particular key into different columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I am very novice on sql programming and would like to know if it is possible to do the following 
I have table x with following data

Table x

```
CODE      CUSTOMER        CLASS
 1            11            F
 1            12            P
 1            13            F
 1            14            F
```

I want to display all the records for CODE=1 into a single record, like this

```
CODE      CUSTOMER_A   CUSTOMER_B   CUSTOMER_C ...
 1            11           12           13
```

I need to display all customers for same CODE and CLASS = F on different columns on a sigle row , the value of CUSTOMER needs to be displayed in CUSTOMER_A column,next value on CUSTOMER_B column and so on.

Comment: You'll need dynamic SQL PIVOT for this. This is usually best handled in application code rather than SQL.

Comment: How do you choose CUSTOMER_A for value 11 (customer) ? What does happen if there are more than 26 customer ? CUSTOMER_AA ? Instead could you have CUSTOMER_011 for value 11 (customer)  ?

Comment: Yes , it could be a different name for the column it doesn't matter, value for the column comes from value of the column CUSTOMER. Max columns are 4 or 5 , no more than that.

Comment: How is "13" included?  Its class is "P" and not "F".

Comment: You're right @GordonLinoff...Keyboard emotion..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping, i understood your problem correctly,

As you mentioned in comment there will be max 4 or 5 customer. i think below query might help. Please check

```
select CODE , 
max(case when rn = 1 then customer end) customer_a ,
max(case when rn = 2 then customer end) customer_b ,
max(case when rn = 3 then customer end) customer_c ,
max(case when rn = 4 then customer end) customer_d ,
max(case when rn = 5 then customer end) customer_e 
from
(
SELECT CODE , CUSTOMER , row_number() over (partition by code order by rowid ) rn
  FROM TABLE_X 
  where code = 1
  and class='F'

)  
group by code
  ;
```

Comment: Yours works awesome!!!!..That's what I want. I have a short code too I gonna try if does work.

Answer (score 0):

Another useful option was next code, dont know if it's correct but works too.

```
  SELECT CODE, 
     MAX(CASE WHEN ROWNUM = 1 THEN customer  END) customer_a ,
     MAX(CASE WHEN ROWNUM = 2 THEN customer  END) customer_c ,
     MAX(CASE WHEN ROWNUM = 3 THEN customer  END) customer_d ,
     MAX(CASE WHEN ROWNUM = 3 THEN customer  END) customer_e
  from TABLE_X
  where code = 1
 and class='F'
GROUP BY code
```